# Bash Extract FULL Path and filename WITHPOUT Extension

Tags: bash

I want to extract the FULL path and FILENAME without Extension.

I do not want just the filename without extension.

Thank you.

Comment: `"${var%.*}"` expands to a version of `$var` with everything after the last `.` removed. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: I got it, thank you.